# How to resolve WPF bindings error: Cannot retrieve value using the binding and no valid fallback value exists

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I created user control which is added to XAML window:

```
<ctrl:MenuControl DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}/>
```

My user control has menu items e.g.:

```
<MenuItem Header="example command" Command="{Binding ExampleCommand}" />
```

Locator defined in App.xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary> 
        <!--Global View Model Locator-->
        <viewModel:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

MainViewModel defined in locator like this:

```
    public MainViewModel Main
    {
        get { return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>(); }
    }
```

Unfortunatelly I got plenty of errors like this:

> System.Windows.Data Information: 10 : Cannot retrieve value using the
>   binding and no valid fallback value exists; using default instead.
>   BindingExpression:Path=ExampleCommand; DataItem=null; target element
>   is 'MenuItem' (Name=''); target property is 'Command' (type
>   'ICommand')

Resharper similarly shows:

> Cannot ressolve symbol due to unknown DataContext.

How should I set datacontext properly?

Comment: Is this a compilation error or you see it in Output window?

Comment: only output window but I consider it to influence performance

Comment: seems ok to me. could you post your Locator resource markup?

Comment: I added locator markup

Comment: So you have ViewModelLocator.Main.ExampleCommand? Is main a singleton or smth?